# Azure Web App Bot - Trigger an event once OAuth has been completed

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, bots, azure-bot-service

I'm following this example to implement the OAuth with Salesforce,
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/examples/basics-oauth/app.js

**Code**

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
    builder.OAuthCard.create(connector, session, connectionName, "Please sign in", "Sign in", (createSignInErr, signInMessage) => {
        if (signInMessage) {
            session.send(signInMessage);
            session.userData.activeSignIn = true;
        } else {
            session.send("Something went wrong trying to sign you in.");
        }
    });
}).on("event", (event) => {         // Handle 'event' activities
        if (event.name == 'tokens/response') {
            // received a TokenResponse, which is how the Azure Bot Service responds with the user token after an OAuthCard
            bot.loadSession(event.address, (err, session) => {
                let tokenResponse = event.value;
                session.send('You are now signed in with token: ' + tokenResponse.token);
                session.userData.activeSignIn = false;
            });
        }
    });
```

At the end, there is a event binding something like `.on("event", (event) => { console.log(event); }`, is not working.

**Problem**
I am able to authenticate the user without any issue. But, not sure how to add a handler for on oAuth complete.

**Update**

Sign in Button was not working on MS Teams so, I rewrote the code like below,

```
var login = (session) => {
    const config = require('config');
    const botConfig = config.get('BOT');
    const connectionName = botConfig.OAUTH_CONNECTION_NAME;
    console.log('address', session.message.address);
    connector.getSignInLink(session.message.address, connectionName, function (getSignInLinkErr, link) {
        var msg = new builder.Message(session)
            .attachments([
                new builder.SigninCard(session)
                    .text("Please click this link to sign in first.")
                    .button("signin", link)
            ]);
        session.send(msg);
        builder.Prompts.text(session, "You must first sign into your account.");
    });
}
bot.dialog('signinPrompt', [
    (session, args) => {
        login(session);
    },
    (session, results) => {
        console.log('results', results);
    },
    (session, results) => {
        console.log('results', results);
    }
]);

bot.dialog('GreetingDialog', [
    (session, args, next) => {
        const isSignedIn = salesforce.isSignedIn(connector, session);
        if (!isSignedIn) {
            session.beginDialog('signinPrompt');
        } else {
            next();
        }
    },
    (session, results, next) => {
        console.log('session userdata', session.userData);
    }
]).triggerAction({
    matches: 'Greeting'
});

bot.on('trigger', function (message) {
    var queuedMessage = message.value;
    var reply = new builder.Message()
        .address(queuedMessage.address)
        .text('This is coming from the trigger: ' + queuedMessage.text);
    bot.send(reply);
});

bot.on("event", (event) => {         // Handle 'event' activities
    if (event.name == 'tokens/response') {
        // received a TokenResponse, which is how the Azure Bot Service responds with the user token after an OAuthCard
        bot.loadSession(event.address, (err, session) => {
            let tokenResponse = event.value;
            session.send('You are now signed in with token: ' + tokenResponse.token);
            session.userData.activeSignIn = false;
        });
    }
});

connector.onInvoke((event, cb) => {
    if (event.name == 'signin/verifyState') {
        // received a MS Team's code verification Invoke Activity
        bot.loadSession(event.address, (err, session) => {
            let verificationCode = event.value.state;
            // Get the user token using the verification code sent by MS Teams
            connector.getUserToken(session.message.address, connectionName, verificationCode, (err, result) => {
                session.send('You are now signed in with token: ' + result.token);
                session.userData.activeSignIn = false;
                cb(undefined, {}, 200);
            });
        });
    } else {
        cb(undefined, {}, 200);
    }
});
```

I was able to get the magic code after the authentication is completed but not able to validate it. I'm really not sure how this oauth callback works, where do you we get the informations after the oauth is complete? I'm stuck here and not able to proceed further. `.on('trigger')`, `.on('event')`, and `.onInvoke` didn't work.

Really appreciate any help!

Comment: are you using csharp ?

Comment: I'm using NodeJS

Comment: are you using  Azure AD v1 or v2 endpoints ?

Comment: I think 'm using v1

Comment: sorry i missed understood you i will adjust my answer with better explanation allow me few minutes

Comment: so when you post to sales force what is the response u r getting cus based on the response you will handle user activity , if success then you may use the success response within response header and the generated token to query over sales force ,,  as i understand from your question , you reached the step of success response right ?

Comment: Which channel are you adding Authentication to?

Comment: I've added it for MS Teams.

Comment: Just double checking here, are you having issues with getting a user authenticated using salesforce's OAuth path, or are you having issues with sending the user a "you have been authenticated" message. It is somewhat unclear within your question.

Comment: I do not have any issues with getting the user authenticated on Salesforce. I'm stuck with sending the user a you have been authenticated message.

Comment: So setting aside sending them a message immediately after verification, other features within your bot utilizing the authenticated salesforce endpoint are working fine correct (accessing profile information and so on)?

Comment: Yes, you're right! The only problem is I am not sure where and how to get the auth confirmation. Here is the video link, https://moustachehome-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/moustacheguyis_moustachehome_onmicrosoft_com/EVTAVNBFHKBNnrY1vGne0mgBWOjbhPwDdXo9a-wuW8wIig?e=6MzemX

Comment: I'd recommend setting some breakpoints in your bot on all three of those locations you aren't sure about in debug mode to see if an event is coming in anywhere and just getting ignored after you receive it.

Comment: I tried it but didn't work! Here is a video link of debug mode, https://moustachehome-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/moustacheguyis_moustachehome_onmicrosoft_com/EUAUoh_ylKxCu023B5GWm0oBdIBaE3IThvbykYK4rL8urQ?e=6zb9sR

Comment: Do you find the breakpoint at line 119 in that video (hit at around the 1:04 point) is getting hit in other situations that aren't authentication? As that would be the standard place to put an authentication confirmation message generally. The bot won't recognize authentication until you've posted the magic number back to it.

Comment: I've 3 waterfall under `signinPrompt` where the #1, sends the auth url to the user and once the user successfully signs into the system, it will trigger #2 where we get the authenticated information such as `code`, `state`, and `magic code`. And, #3 will be triggered when the user enter the magic code in Team which they got on the auth success screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179659/discussion-between-moustacheman-and-mark-b).

Answer (score 0):

SO it looks like you are having 2 issues here.

1. The sign in button will not work in teams out of the box unless you add the bot framework domain to your manifest like `token.botframework.com`.  I will post an example of the full manifest below. the way you are trying will also work, but will not allow login without a magic code.
2. You are not receiving the invoke activity from teams.  For this you need to add a manifest to your teams application. I will post an example of this below, but there is a [documentation page here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-oauth-card#getting-started-with-oauthcard-in-teams) that may help as well.

here is what a manifest will look like, you will need to include the 2 images used in the icon section in the folder and zip it to upload it to teams

```
{
    "$schema": "https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v1.0/manifest/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.0",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "id": "{Your bot's app ID}",
    "packageName": "bot.builder",
    "developer": {
        "name": "{Your Name}",
        "websiteUrl": "https://example.com/",
        "privacyUrl": "https://example.com/privacy",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://example.com/app-tos"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "{Name of your app}"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "A Bot",
        "full": "This app displays information."
    },
     "icons": {
        "outline": "{Required image}",
        "color": "{Required image}"
     },
    "accentColor": "#0099ff",
    "bots": [
        {
            "botId": "{Your bot's app ID}",
            "isNotificationOnly": false,
            "needsChannelSelector": "true",
            "scopes": [
                "personal",
                "team"
            ]
        }
    ],
  "validDomains": [
     "token.botframework.com"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, let me try it out and get back to you!

Comment: Do I need to manually create `manifest.json`? Because I've created a Web App Bot on Azure, I've added OAuth Connection Setting under Bot Settings, Added required channel (Teams in my case), and downloaded the Source Code from Build section. I didn't find any manifest file by default. Also, will it only work whn I upload it team and not while, Bot Management -> Channel -> Team.app?

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work! I've added the `manifest.json` and icons as above. Then, I've zipped the manifest.json along with the icons and installed it to team. I click the Sign in Button, take me to the auth page, and I'll enter the username, password and get the magic code. When I put the magic code in the conversation, it again sends me the oauth card. Looks like, the invoke is not happening.